# How can I forward a primary key sequence in Django safely?

Tags: django, postgresql, sequence

Using Django with a PostgreSQL (8.x) backend, I have a model where I need to skip a block of ids, e.g. after giving out 49999 I want the next id to be 70000 not 50000 (because that block is reserved for another source where the instances are added explicitly with id - I know that's not a great design but it's what I have to work with).

What is the correct/safest place for doing this?

I know I can set the sequence with

```
SELECT SETVAL(
    (SELECT pg_get_serial_sequence('myapp_mymodel', 'id')),
    70000,
    false
);
```

but when does Django actually pull a number from the sequence?
Do I override MyModel.save(), call its super and then grab me a cursor and check with

```
SELECT currval(
    (SELECT pg_get_serial_sequence('myapp_mymodel', 'id'))
);
```

?

I believe that a sequence may be advanced by django even if saving the model fails, so I want to make sure whenever it hits that number it advances - is there a better place than save()?

P.S.: Even if that was the way to go - can I actually figure out the currval for save()'s session like this? if I grab me a connection and cursor, and execute that second SQL statement, wouldn't I be in another session and therefore not get a currval?

Thank you for any pointers.

**EDIT**: I have a feeling that this must be done at database level (concurrency issues) and posted a corresponding PostgreSQL question - [How can I forward a primary key sequence in PostgreSQL safely?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9341890/how-can-i-forward-a-primary-key-sequence-in-postgresql-safely)

Comment: Why not just run that on your database manually and be done with it? Trying to hack a way into Django to do it on the actual instance of the id hitting 49999, it way more work that it's worth. If id's are only safe after 70000, then that's where you should start.

Comment: I agree with Chris. It sounds like any such code would be a pain to test, too.

Comment: The problem with running that manually is that I would have to do that then and there when it occurs. There's more than one gap. They are numbers that are given out by two different systems (online/offline) but end up in the same database. Alternating blocks.

Comment: I'm curious though, what makes you think it involves hacking Django, or lots of work? I would have thought I just need to know the right spot where it should be done. A postgres trigger on sequence update could do this, too, I suppose. I want users to manage these blocks in django admin, so maybe I need a trigger that looks up a django-managed table... I just thought maybe that's not necessary, given only django writes to that database.

Comment: How are you stopping the second system from allocating records in the 70000 range?

Comment: I'm not. It's a website that allocates numbers from "their" blocks, and I just insert them with the given id explicitly specified. The records entered in the Django app are entered manually and should grab the "next available one" but not from the reserved block of ids coming from the website.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My next thought was to not use a sequence for the primary key, but rather *always* specify the id explicitly from a separate counter table which I check/update before using its latest number - that should be safe from concurrency issues. The only problem is that although I have a single place where I add model instances, other parts of django or third-party apps may still rely on an implicit id, which I don't want to break.

But that same mechanism happens to be easily implemented on postgres level - I believe this is the solution:

- Don't use SERIAL for the primary key, use DEFAULT my_next_id()
- Follow the same logic as for "single level gapless sequence" - http://www.varlena.com/GeneralBits/130.php - my_next_id() does an update followed by a select
- Instead of just increasing by 1, check if a boundary was crossed and if so, increase even further

Comment: P.S.: This can actually be done the same way Django-only, I believe. Similar concept but using django's "default" callable for the primary key. Unfortunately a couple of other tasks have taken priority but I'll post the django-only solution within the next two weeks (no hacking needed :-)).

Comment: Unfortunately [Django bug #11390](https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/11390) is currently in the way of a Django-only solution.

Answer (score 0):

As I haven't found an "automated" way of doing this yet, I'm thinking of the following workaround - it would be feasible for my particular situation:

1. Set the sequence with a MAXVALUE 49999 NO CYCLE
2. When 49999 is reached, the next save() will run into a postgres error
3. Catch that exception and reraise as a form error "you've run out of numbers, please reset to the next block then try again"
4. Provide a view where the user can activate the next block, i.e. execute "ALTER SEQUENCE my_seq RESTART WITH 70000 MAXVALUE 89999"

I'm uneasy about doing the restart automatically when catching the exception:

```
try:
    instance.save()
except RunOutOfIdsException:
    restart_id_sequence()
    instance.save()
```

as I fear two concurrent save()'s running out of ids will lead to two separate restarts, and a subsequent violation of the unique constraint. (basically same concept as original problem)