# How can I forward a primary key sequence in PostgreSQL safely?

Tags: postgresql, sequence

Using PostgreSQL (8.x), I need to skip a block of sequence numbers **automatically**, e.g. after giving out 49999 I want the next id to be 70000 not 50000

What is the correct/safest way of doing this?

NB: I originally posted a very similar question [How can I forward a primary key sequence in Django safely?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9307896/how-can-i-forward-a-primary-key-sequence-in-django-safely) but I have the feeling that this must be done at database level (concurrency issues)...

Comment: Man, according to the mentioned question you are __really__ looking for quite some trouble...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe I've found a way:

- Don't use SERIAL for the primary key, use DEFAULT my_next_id()
- Follow the same logic as for "single level gapless sequence" - http://www.varlena.com/GeneralBits/130.php - my_next_id() does an update followed by a select
- Instead of just increasing by 1, check if a boundary was crossed and if so, increase even further

Answer (score 0):

You can use a trigger, that checks the actual value of the sequence after an insert statement and change it for the value that you want.

I think that this snippet should do the job

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION change_sequence() RETURNS TRIGGER AS $change_sequence$
DECLARE
  current_value INTEGER;

BEGIN
  current_value := currval('your_sequence');
  IF current_value = 49999 THEN
    setval ('you_sequence', 70000, false);
  END IF;
  RETURN NULL;
END;
$change_sequence$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;

-- DROP TRIGGER check_pkey ON your_table;
CREATE TRIGGER check_pkey
AFTER INSERT ON your_table
EXECUTE PROCEDURE change_sequence();
```

Comment: Thank you for your response. This will change the primary key rather than the sequence. I could live with the fact that this will be triggered 20000 times, but I think the bigger problem is that the framework I'm using (Django) will use currval() of the sequence for the foreign key of objects created in the same session.

Comment: I edited the snippet. I think that the currval issue can be handled passing the false parameter to setval, if it does not work, you can call setval('your_seq', 69999) and then call nexval

Comment: Thanks for revisiting this! Hmmm, I thought a trigger "AFTER INSERT" would only be triggered after a successful insert, is that correct? An unsuccessful attempt at INSERTing will still pull a nextval(), which means it's possible that an unsuccessful insert pulls 49999 without this trigger being called, followed by a successful insert, where the equality check with 49999 won't work because it pulled 50000...?

Comment: My first thought was to trigger on the sequence update rather than my insert, but I'm starting to not trust sequences - they seem to be just a bit too generous :-)